How to setup a private GoEthereum network
I'm studying Ethreum by creating by own private ethereum network. I have three basic question. I will give as much information as I can to help to get great responses.
My network setup is very simple:

1 server that acts as a bootnde
1 server that acts as signer and node
1 server that acts as node

I used as a guide instructions from this site: https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network
I also have created three accounts on the server that acts and signer and node.
My genesis.json looks like these:
{
    "config": {
      "chainId": 4343,
      "homesteadBlock": 0,
      "eip150Block": 0,
      "eip155Block": 0,
      "eip158Block": 0,
      "byzantiumBlock": 0,
      "constantinopleBlock": 0,
      "petersburgBlock": 0,
      "istanbulBlock": 0,
      "berlinBlock": 0,
      "clique": {
        "period": 5,
        "epoch": 30000
      }
    },
    "difficulty": "1",
    "gasLimit": "80000",
    "extradata": "0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000015988464C8b666C474029418908229209D1B30380000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "alloc": {
      "15988464C8b666C474029418908229209D1B3038": { "balance": "800000000000" },
      "37Ccc32e8E8D6846acc51a5F1A4fb6fD87b18b73": { "balance": "400000000000" },
      "36A62425cA06e12FEA4eda5cc1975B148c73d446": { "balance": "500000000000" }
    }
  }

On the signer node I see messages like this:

INFO [04-24|12:19:33.409] Looking for peers peercount=1 tried=0 static=0


INFO [04-24|12:19:36.014] Successfully sealed new block number=67 sealhash=1a84a8..a7e8ce hash=bd08f3..db2776 elapsed=4.999s


INFO [04-24|12:19:36.015] Commit new sealing work number=68 sealhash=6b95d5..0e7694 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="205.305µs"


INFO [04-24|12:19:41.014] Successfully sealed new block number=68 sealhash=6b95d5..0e7694 hash=c66196..516fb1 elapsed=4.998s


INFO [04-24|12:19:41.014] Commit new sealing work number=69 sealhash=43520b..f23ba7 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="233.505µs"


INFO [04-24|12:19:43.425] Looking for peers peercount=1 tried=0 static=0


INFO [04-24|12:19:46.013] Successfully sealed new block number=69 sealhash=43520b..f23ba7 hash=a2c6ed..70acb4 elapsed=4.998s


INFO [04-24|12:19:46.013] Commit new sealing work number=70 sealhash=9df043..003d09 txs=0 gas=0 fees=0 elapsed="209.205µs"

On the server that act just as a node I see messages like this:

WARN [04-24|12:30:02.224] Served eth_coinbase reqid=3 duration="18.001µs" err="etherbase must be explicitly specified"


INFO [04-24|12:30:06.030] Imported new chain segment number=193 hash=968dfc..036361 blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=15.814ms mgasps=0.000 triedirty=0.00B


INFO [04-24|12:30:10.383] Looking for peers peercount=1 tried=0 static=0


INFO [04-24|12:30:11.038] Imported new chain segment number=194 hash=9a9480..8d1e73 blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=13.298ms mgasps=0.000 triedirty=0.00B


INFO [04-24|12:30:16.026] Imported new chain segment number=195 hash=214458..6ef2eb blocks=1 txs=0 mgas=0.000 elapsed=13.016ms mgasps=0.000 triedirty=0.00B

My questions are: (They are not related)

When I attach to the console (geth attach data/geth.ipc) and run the command eth.accounts on the server that acts as signer and node I saw the three accounts that I have created. But, if I ran the very same command on node2 no accounts are displayed. Why? Shoulnd't it be synced?

In my understanding I was capable of mining some ethereum on my private network. Is it correct? If yes, where can I find them?

I tried to use the command eth.sendTransaction but I failed with the error msg: gas required exceeds allowance (800). How can I fix it?



1/ Accounts aren't synchronized. You don't want nodes to share the private keys.
2/ In "clique" there's no block reward.
3/ The minimum gas required by a transaction is 21000 (a simple ether transfer). You will need to adjust gasLimit for the nodes so it is higher.
